# How to play youtube video link in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to play youtube video link on my php page

youtube link is

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAJK04HOLd0

```
<object width="420" height="315" data="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAJK04HOLd0">
```

i am try this code but it's not working

Comment: @Hridesh you can check out this link [http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp)

Comment: yes its work but when i change data path its not work                                       like data-"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAJK04HOLd0" its not work

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the video file in `<iframe>`. Try this sample code,

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VAJK04HOLd0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Look at the last part of the url `https://www.youtube.com/embed/VAJK04HOLd0`,

```
VAJK04HOLd0
```

Which is the youtube video code. If you want to change the video change the code.

Comment: yes its wok but when i change src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iayQnNuctgo" like this it's not work please help

Comment: @Hirdesh I edited the answer. You can change the youtube video code to play different videos as I explained.

Answer (score 0):

To embed YouTube videos, you should be using an iframe.

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://example.com/?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not connected to php.
You will want to include `&autoplay=1` to the youtube string.